# What Is Regularisation Loss in TensorFlow API? It Doesn't Align With Any Other Loss Function

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, object-detection, tensorboard, object-detection-api

I'm training an EfficientDet V7 model using the V2 model zoo and have the following output in TensorBoard:
[image: TensorBoard Loss Plots]

This is great, you can see that my classification and localisation losses are dropping to low levels (I'll worry about overfitting later if this is a separate issue) - but regularisation loss is still high and this is keeping my total loss at quite high levels. I can't seem to a) find a clear explanation (for a newbie) on what I'm looking at with the regularisaton loss (what does it represent in this context) and b) suggestions as to why it might be so high.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, regularization loss is something like a L2 loss computed on the **weights** of your neural net. Minimization of this loss tends to shrink the values of the weights.
It is a regularization (hence the name) technique, which can help with such problems as over-fitting (maybe [this article](https://heartbeat.fritz.ai/deep-learning-best-practices-regularization-techniques-for-better-performance-of-neural-network-94f978a4e518) can help if you want to know more).

Bottom line: You don't have to do anything about it.

Comment: I will use the link provided for further research - thank you.